# The while loop is not repeating itself upon throwing garbage values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a while loop using the 'not' keyword but when I am doing so, the loop is accepting garbage values as well(for eg. bjskdjb) which is not the condition set for the while/for loop.

When I am running the for loop instead, it is throwing a syntax error.

What are the mistakes I am doing here(both using for loop and while loop) ?

I have tried doing it with for loop and while loop.

```
def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    while playerchoice not in ('X' , 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
        if playerchoice == 'X':
            return ['X' , 'O']
        else:
            return ['O', 'X']
askplayerchoice()

'''
# Using For loop I am getting a syntax error. 

def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    for playerchoice not in ('X' , 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
        if playerchoice == 'X':
            return ['X' , 'O']
        else:
            return ['O', 'X']
askplayerchoice()

'''
```

I am expecting the code to keep asking the user to enter either 'X' or 'O' until the user enters correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from the loop to the function caller in the first pass itself, because you use `return` inside loop. Hence, whatever is the value other than `'X'`, `['O', 'X']` is returned.

```
def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    while playerchoice not in ('X' , 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
    if playerchoice == 'X':
        return ['X' , 'O']
    elif playerchoice == 'O':
        return ['O', 'X']

print(askplayerchoice())
```

You can also make use of an infinite loop `while True:` here, like so:

```
def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    while True:
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
        if playerchoice == 'X':
            return ['X' , 'O']
        elif playerchoice == 'O':
            return ['O', 'X']

print(askplayerchoice())
```

Comment: Thanks... Worked for while loop.Can you also tell me why this code is not working with For loop.. def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    for playerchoice not in ('X' , 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
    if playerchoice == 'X':
        return ['X' , 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']
askplayerchoice()

Comment: @PrashantMishra, `for` does not work like `while`. `for x in (..,..)` will take values from `(.., ..)` one item at a time in each iteration. Try printing: `for x in (1,2): print(x)`. What you did `for .. not in (.., ..)` is syntactically wrong.

Comment: yes, you are right.. I got it now !! BIG THANK YOU for clearing the confusion. Happy New year 2019 to you ! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a try catch block and throw an exception when the entered string does not match your desired value. I have updated your code for the same. Below is the snippet :

```
def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    while playerchoice.lower() not in ('X' , 'O'):
        try:
            playerchoice = str(input('Enter X or O: '))
            if playerchoice.lower() not in ['x','o']:
                raise ValueError('A very specific bad thing happened.')
            if playerchoice.lower() == 'x':
                return ['X' , 'O']
            else:
                return ['O', 'X']
        except ValueError:
            playerchoice = ''


askplayerchoice()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning a value within the while loop, regardless of what the user input is, and that's causing the loop to end. You need to change your `else` condition to `else if`:

```
if playerchoice == 'X':
     return ['X' , 'O']
elif playerchoice == 'O':
     return ['O', 'X']
```

Comment: Thanks.. What is wrong in this condition: for playerchoice not in ('X' , 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')

Answer (score 0):

First you were initializing `playerchoice = ''` but inside the loop you were only checking for `playerchoice == 'X'`. But you didn't check for `playerchoice == 'O'`. therefore it went to the else and got out of the loop.

This should do the work:

```
def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
    while playerchoice not in('X', 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
        if playerchoice == 'X':
            return ['X', 'O']
        elif playerchoice == 'O':
            return ['O', 'X']
askplayerchoice()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use return, the while loop will be stopped.
Try this code, it will keep asking.

```
def askplayerchoice():
    playerchoice = ''
    while playerchoice not in ('X' , 'O'):
        playerchoice = input('Enter X or O: ')
        if playerchoice == 'X':
            print('X' , 'O')
        else:
            print('O', 'X')
    return askplayerchoice()
askplayerchoice()
```